# How to write pojo class for this xml by using JAXB?

Tags: jaxb

Please any one help me. How to write Pojo class for this xml by using JAXB annotations.
The following is the sample code:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ERRORFILE xmlns="http://www.corelogic.com/fps/Returned_error">
    <ERROR_LIST listCount="2">
       <ERROR>
            <ERROR_CODE>11</ERROR_CODE>
            <ERROR_MSG>sad</ERROR_MSG>
            <ACTUAL_HEADER_COUNT>2</ACTUAL_HEADER_COUNT>
            <EXPECTED_HEADER_COUNT>3</EXPECTED_HEADER_COUNT>
            <REC_NUMBERS totalCount="3">
                <REC_NUMBER>4</REC_NUMBER>
                <REC_NUMBER>5</REC_NUMBER>
                <REC_NUMBER>6</REC_NUMBER>
            </REC_NUMBERS>
        </ERROR>
        <ERROR>
            <ERROR_CODE>22</ERROR_CODE>
            <ERROR_MSG>bad</ERROR_MSG>
            <ACTUAL_HEADER_COUNT>4</ACTUAL_HEADER_COUNT>
            <EXPECTED_HEADER_COUNT>3</EXPECTED_HEADER_COUNT>
            <REC_NUMBERS totalCount="2">
                <REC_NUMBER>4</REC_NUMBER>
                <REC_NUMBER>5</REC_NUMBER>
            </REC_NUMBERS>
        </ERROR>
    </ERROR_LIST>
</ERRORFILE>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will help:

### Number of Classes

In JAXB Java classes correspond to complex types in XML Schema.  You are generally going to need a class per type of complex element.  Based on your document you will need classes for:  `ErrorFile`, `ErrorList`, `Error`, `RecNumbers`, etc.

### Mapping Metadata

By default JAXB doesn't require any mapping metadata.  Node names are derived from the corresponding Java names.  Since all your elements are upper case, you are going to need to specify names using the `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ERRORFILE")
public class ErrorFile {
}
```

### XML Attributes

By default JAXB represents everything as an XML element.  To map something to an XML attribute you need to use the `@XmlAttribute` annotation.

### NAMESPACES

Since your XML document is namespace qualified you will need to leverage the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to map this:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

### Grouping Elements

If your `ERROR_LIST` and `REC_NUMBERS` elements were simple grouping elements that wrapped collection data then you could do the following:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="ERROR_LIST")
@XmlElement(name="ERROR")
public List<Error> getErrorList() {
    return errorList;
}
```

But since you have an extra bit of data mapped as an XML attribute at that level you will need to represent it as a class:

```
@XmlElement(name="ERROR_LIST")
public ErrorList getErrorList() {
    return errorList;
}
```

For More Information:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html